# Cross-origin error in request made by react-query

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js, cors, react-query

In my project, I use Typescript, React and Next.js.
To fetch data from a API, I did two approachs:

#### Approach 1

This approach works fine when I call `getAllDatasets` from `getServerSideProps`:

**ckanApi.ts**

```js
// BASE_URL = http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/

import axios from "axios"
const ApiCkan = axios.create(process.env.BASE_URL)
export default ApiCkan
```

**datasetLib.ts**

```js
export function listDatasets() {
  return ApiCkan
    .get<DatasetListResponse>( `package_list` )
    .then(({ data }) => data.result )
}


export function getDataset(id: string): Promise<DatasetProps> {
  return ApiCkan
    .get<DatasetInfoResponse>( `package_show?id=${id}` )
    .then(({ data }) => data.result)
}


export async function getAllDatasets() {
  let allDatasets : DatasetProps[] = []
  const datasetsIDs = (await listDatasets()) 

  for (let i = 0; i < datasetsIDs.length; i++ ) {  
    allDatasets.push( await getDataset( datasetsIDs[i]) )
  }

  return allDatasets
}
```

**datasets.tsx**

```js
 export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      allDatasets: (await getAllDatasets())
    }
  }

}
```

#### Approach 2

I decided put React-Query following the example:
https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-nextjs

**_App.js**

```js
// ...
import {Hydrate, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from 'react-query'
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(
    () => 
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            staleTime: 1000 * 120, // 120 seconds
          },
        },
      })
  )

  return(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <GlobalStyle />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Hydrate>
    <ReactQueryDevtools />
  </QueryClientProvider>
  )  
}

// ...
```

**Default.tsx**

```js
//...
import {dehydrate, QueryClient, useQuery} from 'react-query'

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient()
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery('myData', getAllDatasets )

   return {
     props: {
       dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
     },
   }
}


export default function Default({children}: Props ) {
    const { data } = useQuery('myData', getAllDatasets)

    // ...
```

In this approach I get a network error "cross-origin request blocked... ...'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing on CORS..."

Okay, this needs to defined on server configs. But **why this error happen in the second approach but not in the first?** Maybe I'm doing something wrong...

I'm trying to use React-Query lib to understand your meaning, and decide if it is good or not for the project. But I don't know yet how it works.

Comment: The difference is that in your first approach the request is made from the server-side only. In your second approach, while you still get the initial data from the server as well, `react-query` will also refetch those queries on the client too, causing the CORS error. See https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-hydration for details.

Comment: @juliomalves I have a doubt about getServerSideProps, and getStaticProps: these functions keep running in all lifecycle of the of the page/application? Should I try to fetch all my data in App.js for have this in all my application? If yes, I would not use react-query in this project, I guess...

Comment: _"these functions keep running in all lifecycle of the of the page/application?"_ - Not entirely sure what you mean by that. [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props) is used to statically generate a page, and only runs during build time. [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) enables SSR and runs on each request to the page it's in.